# converting from std::string to const char* causes 'Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to unaddressable byte(s)' error in valgrind

Tags: c++, string, http, valgrind

While using the **libmicrohttpd** library, I came across an odd error when converting a `string` to `const char *` and calling `MHD_create_response_from_buffer` with it.

This causes the webpage response to come back badly malformed, occasionally displaying binary data and, a little more rarely, making the browser think it is a file and downloading it.

What makes this really odd is that the error does not show up if I send a regular const char, like
`const char *cstring = "this is a page";`
only when I'm converting from a `string` to `const char *` like
`const char *cstring = page.c_str();`

the Valgrind output:

```
==11105== Thread 2:
==11105== Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==11105==    at 0x617464B: send (send.c:31)
==11105==    by 0x565986F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmicrohttpd.so.10.27.0)
==11105==    by 0x565737D: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmicrohttpd.so.10.27.0)
==11105==    by 0x565DA3C: MHD_run_from_select (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmicrohttpd.so.10.27.0)
==11105==    by 0x565DC8A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmicrohttpd.so.10.27.0)
==11105==    by 0x565DDA1: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmicrohttpd.so.10.27.0)
==11105==    by 0x876B0A3: start_thread (pthread_create.c:309)
==11105==    by 0x617362C: clone (clone.S:111)
==11105==  Address 0xe499448 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 56 free'd
==11105==    at 0x4C2A360: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:507)
==11105==    by 0x401CA5: http_connect(void*, MHD_Connection*, char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, unsigned long*, void**) (in /home/shpoople/projects/http/main)
==11105==    by 0x5656F70: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmicrohttpd.so.10.27.0)
==11105==    by 0x5658427: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmicrohttpd.so.10.27.0)
==11105==    by 0x565D988: MHD_run_from_select (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmicrohttpd.so.10.27.0)
==11105==    by 0x565DC8A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmicrohttpd.so.10.27.0)
==11105==    by 0x565DDA1: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmicrohttpd.so.10.27.0)
==11105==    by 0x876B0A3: start_thread (pthread_create.c:309)
==11105==    by 0x617362C: clone (clone.S:111)
==11105==
```

And the function for sending the data (found at [this page](https://gnunet.org/svn/libmicrohttpd/doc/examples/simplepost.c) and only modified to use `std::string`):

```
static int send_page (struct MHD_Connection *connection, std::string page) {
    int ret;
    struct MHD_Response *response;
    const char* cstring = page.c_str();

    response = MHD_create_response_from_buffer (strlen (cstring), (void *) cstring, MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT);

    if (!response) {
        return MHD_NO;
    }

    ret = MHD_queue_response(connection, MHD_HTTP_OK, response);
    MHD_destroy_response (response);

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parameter `std::string page` is a local variable. Its memory is freed when this function finishes.

On the other hand, the function `MHD_run_from_select` and related apparently run on a separate thread. When that thread tries to access a buffer, the memory of `std::string page` has already been freed.

You should make sure the buffer stays alive, either by allocating it differently or by blocking the major thread until you get the response.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The function has a flag for copying the buffer memory, `MHD_RESPMEM_MUST_COPY`

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have solved it on my own. Sorry about asking an unnecessary question.

The problem was solved by changing the third argument on `MHD_create_response_from_buffer` from `MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT` to `MHD_RESPMEM_MUST_COPY`

Again, sorry about that.